# .net core 2.1 "POST" an IFormFile using Postman - the application completed without reading the entire request body

Tags: c#, post, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, iformfile

I'm working on a dotnet core WebAPI 2.1 and I can't find a way of sending to into the Body an image.

The controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost("api/image")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]IFormFile file)
    {
        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

And this is my Postman call:
[image]

This call is never finishing as the `Kestrel` is failing 
[image]

I've already tried to use `Consumes`

```
[Consumes("application/json", "application/json-patch+json", "multipart/from-data")]
```

Also in postman, I have set Content-Type to multipart/form-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing it like this. Use the same request in postman you are using now. This is just crude boilerplate method but you get the idea.

Also, dont forget to set headers of your request in postman to: Content-Type: multipart/form-data

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/image")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> InsertNewMerchant()
{
        // your form data is here
             var formData = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;
             HttpFileCollection files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;


            if (files.Count == 1)
            {
            // this is the file you need 
                var image = files[0];
                    // do something with the file
            }
    return StatusCode(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In dotnet-core `HttpContext` have been removed. Anyway, your solution it does work if we are using it like this `var files = Request.Form.Files;`

Answer (score 17):

I found the solution for .Net Core 2.1/2.2 [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8311#issuecomment-415968775)

[POST multiple files from POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5zUc.png)

[POST single file from POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxvwJ.png)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadSingleFile([FromForm(Name = "file")] IFormFile file)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        var IDsList = new IDsList();

        try
        {
            var id = SaveFile(file);
            IDsList.Files.Add(new IDsList.FileInfo() { id = id, fileName = file.FileName });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }

        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(IDsList), "application/json");
    }

    [HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles([FromForm(Name = "files")] ICollection<IFormFile> files)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        //var files = Request.Form.Files?.GetFiles("files");
        String message = String.Empty;
        int filesCounter = 0;
        var IDsList = new IDsList();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.Length == 0)
                message = message + $"errorDescription {file.FileName}\n";

            try
            {
                var id = SaveFile(file);
                IDsList.Files.Add(new IDsList.FileInfo() { id = id, fileName = file.FileName });
                filesCounter++;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                message = $"{message}{ex.Message}\n";
            }
        }

        IDsList.message = $"Amount: {filesCounter}.\n{message}";

        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(IDsList), "application/json");
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems like there is an error problem with `Postman macOS application`. When I'm using the `postman chrome extension` everything works as expected.

**MacOS app**
[image: MacOS app]

**Chrome extension**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I tried and it worked. Maybe you forget to do something.
Remove **[FromBody]** attribute.

```
    [HttpPost("api/image")]
    public IActionResult Post(IFormFile file)
    {
        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

Postman automatically attaches the correct **Content-Type**, select **form-data** option in body section and add your file with **file** key.

It should work.

Comment: I've tried that and for some reason, it doesn't work. @Bola's solution seems to be a good workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered, but you seem to having decided for an workaround. There is nothing wrong with your endpoint nor with the Postman request, I had the same issue and installing the native Postman for my OS solved the problem https://www.getpostman.com/apps