# The Input was not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

While calling an apiController method from Postman I encountered a problem.

the method with params mentioned in Postman client call below method

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Register([FromBody]UserDto userDto)
    {
        // map dto to entity
        //var user = _mapper.Map<User>(userDto);
        return Ok(new
        {
            userDto
        });

        //try
        //{
        //    // save 
        //    _userService.Create(user, userDto.Password);
        //    return Ok();
        //}
        //catch (AppException ex)
        //{
        //    // return error message if there was an exception
        //    return BadRequest(new { message = ex.Message });
        //}
    }
```

which maps the UserDto..

```
public class UserDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

but instead I get the error below :

[image: Postman Client]

Comment: FromBody is for JSON data. You are passing Form data. Those are not compatible. Use Body > Raw in Postman and put the JSON there. Otherwise, use a more proper tool like Swagger

Comment: FYI ... This is really a Postman question.

Comment: You can also use `[FromForm]` instead of FromBody if you have to use form data encoding. I believe it will also infer this if you skip the attribute altogether.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Did that too [{ "Id": 1, "FirstName": "Jason", "LastName": "Bond", "Username": "Jason",
"Password": "helllo"}].. same result

Comment: @Jason That's because your method is set to receive a single entity, whereas you just tried passing an array of entities.

Comment: For the temp code used above after mentioning correct JSON type it returned as expected but for actual code `_userService.Create(user, userDto.Password);
            return Ok();` an unexpected exception at console appears.. `*info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32] Connection id "0HLHE2K4LHFNC", Request id "0HLHE2K4LHFNC:00000001": the application completed without reading the entire request body.* `

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51424273/net-core-2-1-post-an-iformfile-using-postman-the-application-completed-with

Answer (score 0):

[image: Postman image]

Use raw option and select json from dropdown
and add your dto value in the body.

**Raw**

```
{
"FirstName" : "yourname",
"LastName": "lastname"
}
```

Comment: That works just for the temp code I put in.. For actual code it seems some exception..`**info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
      Connection id "0HLHE2K4LHFNC", Request id "0HLHE2K4LHFNC:00000001": the application completed without reading the entire request body.**`